# Can Cisco Catalyst switch get IP from DHCP server?

Tags: cisco, switch, dhcp, cisco-catalyst

This may be stupid question as I don't have much knowledge in networking.

Anyways, I have Cisco Catalyst 2960 switch and I'm curios if I can configure it to get IP configuration from DHCP server, like all other devices on network.

Now, I have to write it's IP configuration manually, but it would be nice if that can be handled by DHCP server.

Comment: Looks like Jordan Head already provided the answer you were looking for. With that said: I am curious as to why you would want a managed switch like the Cisco Catalyst 2960 to obtain an IP address via DHCP. I feel like benefits of manually setting the IP greatly outweigh dynamic allocation. Just looking for some insight into your train of thought.

Comment: There's a million ways to skin a cat.. In this case DHCP server could be used to assign a particular address to the requesting source MAC address of the switch or SVI, thus the DHCP server will do some record keeping

Comment: @nak, while I personally like to configure the IP on network devices, I have seen this used in locations where they anticipate changes such as DNS servers, gateways, or subnet masks and this allows devices to relearn these changes automatically without someone having to touch every device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify an interface to receive an address from DHCP like this.

```
configure terminal
interface (int-name-num)
ip address dhcp
```

This guide gives way more detail into DHCP features - [Cisco DHCP Client Configuration](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/12-4t/dhcp-12-4t-book/config-dhcp-client.html#GUID-8BC4B08B-0436-42B6-8E3A-021DE842A893)

You should note that there are additional commands to the ones I listed, but they are optional.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's 2960, then it's only Layer 2 device, you can't assign the IP directly on the interface, however, you can use SVI (Switch Virtual Interface).

For example, assign Fa0/1 to vlan 100

then

Interface Vlan 100

ip address dhcp

!

Answer (score 0):

The Catalyst 2950 Does not appear to me to have the option to allow it's VLAN's to accept DHCP..  If you use a Catalyst 2960-S, then you can set the vlan to procure it's IP address through DHCP.

I think the fundamental problem you are having is the switch does not have the capability.  I only say that because I have both switches and my 2950 won't accept the VLAN 100 ip address dhcp command..

Comment: OP asked about a 2960 and not a 2950.